# Scala: How to get values out a a tuple in a complex expression

Tags: scala, tuples

I am analyzing some Scala code written in a codebase written by others and I am trying to refactor the code. 
What I want to accomplish is: **Display the value of the statusUpdate variable, and also capture its internal variables like taskRun.filesFound.
I want to see what is being passed into the statusUpdate varible upstream to some other code, before it is written into that ChannelBuffer with the copiedBuffer method.**

So, the code description is as below and in that code there is a method that is is defined in a trait which is in turn is mixed into some other class:

```
def sendApiUpdate(tasks:Map[String,FileTaskState]) = future{
    val statusUpdate =  MyTaskStatus(tasks.map(tuple=>
          (tuple._1, TaskStatus(
          tuple._2.task.name,
          tuple._2.taskId,
          tuple._2.task.taskState.dispName,
          tuple._2.taskRun.trawledTime,
          tuple._2.taskRun.filesDiscovered,
          tuple._2.taskRun.filesWorkedOn
        ))).toMap)
           dispatch(someUrl, ChannelBuffer.copiedBuffer(write(statusUpdate).getBytes("UTF-8")   ))
    }
```

where  **MyTaskStatus** is a case class as below:

```
case class MyTaskStatus(taskMap:Map[String, TaskStatus])
```

tasks is:

```
tasks: Map[String, FileTaskState]
```

and FileTaskState is a case class as follows:

```
case class FileTaskState(trawler: ActorRef, taskId: String, runId: String, taskRun) 
//there are more field values but I left them out
```

filesDiscovered is:

```
 def filesDiscovered = noFilesDiscovered.getOrElse(0L)
```

Also, in the following line of code:

```
 tuple._2.taskRun.filesDiscovered

 taskRun is one of the fields of case class FileTaskState
 taskRun is:

 taskRun: TaskRun
 and TaskRun is a case class described as below:

 case class TaskRun( taskId: String, noFilesDiscovered)
```

---

Update:

I would like to extract the values associated with the tuples in the tasks.map(...) in their separate variable. 
for example, I would like to extract tuple._2.taskRun.filesDiscovered into: val filesDisc = <>
The purpose is to help me with refactoring.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"?  Look at in a debugger?  If so, set a breakpoint on the dispatch() line and look.  Log?  Then add a log statement in the same place?  These are way too obvious answers, so I suspect you mean something else entirely.

Comment: Yes, I did not mean 'capture' actually. I am going to update the question. What I was  looking for a way to extract this one value: tuple._2.taskRun.filesDiscovered, for a different purpose